# The polynomial $X-2Y$ in $\Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]$ is irredicible

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

We have the ring $\Bbb Z_{13}$ and the polynomial $f(X,Y):=X-2Y  \in \Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]$.

We would like to prove two things:

1) The ideal $\langle X-2Y \rangle \trianglelefteq \Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y] $ is prime, but not maximal.

2) The polynomial $X-2Y $ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]$.

What are in general the teqniques one can follow, in order to show that a polynomial is irreducible in $K[X,Y]$, where $K$ is a field?

**Answer.** In the first one, it's a clasical teqnique to define the ring epimorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]\longrightarrow \Bbb Z_{13}[Y],\ f(X,Y)\longmapsto \phi(f(X,Y)):= f(2Y,Y)$ and then apply the 1st Isomorphism Theorem for Rings. So, it is
$$\frac{\Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]}{\langle X-2Y\rangle } \cong \Bbb Z_{13}[Y].$$
Then $\Bbb Z_{13}[Y]$ is an integral domain, but *not* a field. Equivalently, $\langle X-2Y \rangle$ is prime, but *not* maximal.

But any ideas for the other questions?

**Idea.** We know that if $R$ is an integral domain, $aT+b \in R[T]$ is irreducible in $R[T]$, if $a\in U(R)$ is invertible.

So, can we clame that it we take $f(X,Y)$ in $(\Bbb Z_{13}[Y])[X]=\Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]$, then $X-2Y=1\cdot X-2Y \in (\Bbb Z_{13}[Y])[X]$ and $1\in U((\Bbb Z_{13}[Y])[X])=U(\Bbb Z_{13}[Y])=\Bbb Z_{13}^*$ and thus $f(X,Y)$ is irreducible in $(\Bbb Z_{13}[Y])[X]=\Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]$?

Comment: If the polynomial was not irreducible, what would the ideal generated by it look like?

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your comment. If $X-2Y$ was not irreducible, there were $a(X,Y),b(X,Y) \in \Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]\backslash \Bbb Z_{13}^*$ s.t. $X-2Y=a(X,Y)b(X,Y)$. Now?

Comment: So $ab\in(X-2Y)$ but $a,b\notin (X-2Y)$, right? Does that match with your previous work?

Comment: Nice idea. You say that in 1) we proved that the generated ideal is prime. So, as we wrote it in this form, $a$ or $b$ must be in $(X-2Y)$. But why do you claim that $a,b\notin (X-2Y)$?

Comment: Well, what would happen if $a$ or $b$ were in $(X-2Y)$? Try writing the one that is as $c(X,Y)(X-2Y)$ and seeing what happens. You should arrive at a contradiction pretty quickly.

Comment: Ok. Let's assume that $a(X,Y)\in (X-2Y)\iff \exists c(X,Y)\in \Bbb Z_{13}[X,Y]:\ a(X,Y)=c(X,Y)(X-2Y)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94625/discussion-between-kreiser-and-chris).

Comment: Is this question so bad? :(